# Datatypes are not preserved when a pandas dataframe partitioned and saved as parquet file using pyarrow

Tags: python-3.x, pyarrow

Datatypes are not preserved when a pandas data frame partitioned and saved as parquet file using pyarrow.

**Case 1: Saving a partitioned dataset - Data Types are NOT preserved**

```
# Saving a Pandas Dataframe to Local as a partioned parquet file using pyarrow
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [77,32,234],'name':['agan','bbobby','test'] })
path = 'test'
partition_cols=['age']
print('Datatypes before saving the dataset')
print(df.dtypes)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_to_dataset(table, path, partition_cols=partition_cols, preserve_index=False)


# Loading a dataset partioned parquet dataset from local
df = pq.ParquetDataset(path, filesystem=None).read_pandas().to_pandas()
print('\nDatatypes after loading the dataset')
print(df.dtypes)
```

**Output:**

```
Datatypes before saving the dataset
age      int64
name    object
dtype: object

Datatypes after loading the dataset
name      object
age     category
dtype: object
```

**Case 2: Non-partitioned dataset - Data types are preserved**

```
import pandas as pd
print('Saving a Pandas Dataframe to Local as a parquet file without partitioning using pyarrow')
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [77,32,234],'name':['agan','bbobby','test'] })
path = 'test_without_partition'
print('Datatypes before saving the dataset')
print(df.dtypes)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_to_dataset(table, path, preserve_index=False)


# Loading a dataset partioned parquet dataset from local
df = pq.ParquetDataset(path, filesystem=None).read_pandas().to_pandas()
print('\nDatatypes after loading the dataset')
print(df.dtypes)
```

**Output**:

```
Saving a Pandas Dataframe to Local as a parquet file without partitioning using pyarrow
Datatypes before saving the dataset
age      int64
name    object
dtype: object

Datatypes after loading the dataset
age      int64
name    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obvious way to do this. Please refer to below JIRA issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6114

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# Convert DataFrame to Apache Arrow Table
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

# Parquet with Brotli compression
pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet')
```